# How can I get the Module / Controller / Action for a given path from the Magento Admin area?

Tags: magento

I am to the point where I am extending Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard locally in my module to have access to its match() method, but of course, from the Magento admin it is treated differently from a front-facing store.

Before I waste hours looking into this, is there a simple way to properly populate an instance of Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http/Zend_Controller_Request_Http with the same information it is given on a normal front (read: non-admin) page load (i.e. category page, search page, cms page), but from the admin area based on the path (assuming a given store)?

Ideally, it would look something like:

```
/** @var $request Zend_Controller_Request_Http */
$request = Mage::getModel('namespace_module/foo')->getHttpRequestByPath($uri, $store);
```

Note: In the example, store is optional and '$uri' would be something like:

- www.store.com/
- www.store.com/faq
- www.store.com/foo/category/mens
- www.store.com/bar/product/xyz

Not looking for hacks, but wouldn't mind a shove in the right direction. I am using Magento EE 1.11.

Answer (score 1):

`Mage::app()->getRequest()` will return `Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http`. From there you can call methods like:

```
->getControllerName();
->getActionName();
```

When working with the admin store, I assume a store_id of `Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID`.

Is this what you were looking to achieve, or do you have a different goal in mind?

Comment: My goal is to mimic the behavior of getRequest() for a given URL as a parameter to a function. If I do that from the Admin store, I'm going to get the request for the current controller. I need the "fake" request info.